# How to track active screen in outlook mail using add-in

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins

i'm running timer on task pane Add-in in outlook. when user inactive means if user switch to other tab I need to stop timer and when user back click on outlook mail, I need to resume timer. can anyone guide how to do this?
[image]

Comment: Is it a web add-in or COM based one (VSTO)?

Comment: it is web add-in (outlook add-in task pane)

Comment: `OfficeJS` doesn't provide any events for that.

Comment: Are you sure that they suspend the timer when the user switches to another window?

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide any events for that. You may consider posting your suggestion to the Tech Community at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions, feature requests are considered when the team goes through our planning process. Don't forget to use the Github label: “Type: product feature request”.

In case of COM based add-ins (VSTO) you could handle the [Inspector.Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) an [Inspector.Deactivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.deactivate) events for the inspector windows in Outlook. If you need to deal with Explorer windows you may consider using the [Explorer.Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activate(method))

Comment: Correct, we donot support any event for such a scenario to track active screen for web addins We recommend to upvote or create a new Tech Community item, this will give us visibility of the commonality of it and will help with our prioritization. If we end up working on this issue we will re-activate as needed.